# Pseudo random ordering of integers

Tags: random

I remember an old retro effect for a screen resolution of $320\times 240$. You would iterate the pixels in a linear fashion so there are $76800$ pixels. You could iterate then one by one starting at pixel  $0$ and ending with pixel $76800-1$. However, there was some clever trick using an and mask and multiplication or addition with some magic constants. I don't remember the specifics. This resulted in a pseudo-random iteration over the pixels. No pixel was ever visited twice and all pixels were visited. How can this be done? How should I approach this problem? What is this problem called?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods. For example, it turns out that $p=76800+1$ is prime; therefore one can take any $k$ with $1\le k<p$ and then has that $ki\equiv kj\pmod p$ implies $i\equiv j\pmod p$. Especially, $ki\bmod p$ iterates over $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ as $i$ runs from $0$ to $p-1$:

```
#define K 47465  
#define P (320*240+1)
ki = K;
for (;;) {
   setpixel(ki-1);
   ki += K; 
   if (ki>=P) {
       ki -= P;
       if (ki==0) break;
   }
}
```

(I defined $K$ to be close to th egolden ratio times $p$).
This is not "good" pseudorandom however as the pixels appear "too" uniformly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it on real quick and it really iterates through each pixel exactly once. Impressive! But it has a very regular pattern for all values of K i tried, since each pixel is K pixels apart. Perhaps this is the base of the algorithm and then some other operation can make it more irregular?

Comment: I found this interesting link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: I tried with a=4013, c=4223, m=76800 just to give some numbers that satisfied the constraint specified. But the period was 1024 and not 76800... Perhaps I'm missunderstanding something, but the LCG feels relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using a Linear Congruential Generator (LCG). It's a very basic pseudo-random generator. The state is contained entirely in the last produced number and the next random number in the range is obtained as.

$x_{n+1} = (ax_n + c) \mod m;$

Where $a$, $c$, and $m$ are constants that can be used to very the series. Also $x_0$ is the seed or initial value.

Also the series is know to have a period of $m$ if and only if (from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator))

1. $c$ and $m$ are relatively prime,
2. $a - 1$ is divisible by all prime factors of $m$
3. $a - 1$ is a multiple of $4$ if $m$ is a multiple of $4$.

For this particular case, as the period should be $320 \times 240=76800$ we let

- $m = 76800$
- $c$ can be set to any value not sharing any divisiors with $m$ such as $7$.
- $a = 3 \times 5 \times 4 \times k + 1$ where $k$ is any multiplier larger than 1.

Varying $x_0, c, k$ should give various interesting dissolve effects.

I wrote a small C-program with `c = 7`, `k = 77` and `a = 3 * 5 * 4 * k + 1`

[image: Retro disolve]

```
#include <unistd.h>
// Linear Congruential Generator
int main() {
    const int w = 320, h = 240;
    const int m = w * h;
    const int c = 7;
    const int k = 77;
    const int a = 3 * 5 * 4 * k + 1;
    const int speed = 1500;
    unsigned int buffer[w * h];
    int index = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        buffer[index] = 0xffffffff;
        index = (a * index + c) % m;
        if (i % speed == 0) write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        buffer[index] = 0xff000000;
        index = (a * index + c) % m;
        if (i % speed == 0) write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Test it like so:

```
$gcc a.c && ./a.out | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb32 -video_size 320x240 -i -
```